# API call using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, node.js, post, next.js

I am currently building a Chat APP using ReactJS and NodeJS, I want to understand the behavior of how the API call is being made.

```
const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState("");

        setNewMessage("");
        const { data } = await axios.post(
          "http://localhost:5000/api/message",
          {
            content: newMessage,
            chatId: selectedChat._id,
          },
          config
        );
```

When I am doing a post request the NewMessage inside content contains the previous value of newMessage even though I have setNewMessage to empty. Why is this happening?